# How do I style my View in react-native for making ribbon?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, expo, stylesheet

I want to design a View of react-native but am unable to achieve the same.

Just follow the attached link to get the idea of what I am trying to make the component look like.

A Huge amount of Thanks in advance.

[Sample Like this](http://prntscr.com/pp8rbz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update values depend on your requirement.

```
    <View>
      <View
        style={{
          width: 120,
          padding: 10,
          paddingLeft: 20,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          height: 40,
          borderTopRightRadius: 3,
          borderBottomRightRadius: 3,
        }}>
        <Text style={{color: '#FFF', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Overview</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          width: 0,
          height: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          borderRightWidth: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 20,
          borderRightColor: 'transparent',
          borderTopColor: 'red',
          transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}],
        }}
      />
    </View>
```